# Excel 2010: if( , , "") not treated the same as blank for pivot table group by date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to group by date in an Excel 2010 pivot table.

The column with dates (i.e., the one want to group by), should be the latest date of 2 other columns if neither is null, or blank. i.e., with a formula like:

`=IF(AND(A4 <> "", B4 <> ""), MAX(A4,B4), "")`

Normally, this `""`in the `IF()` formula acts the same as an empty cell. In this case, it is preventing me from grouping by date in the Pivot Table. If I filter the date column by `(Blanks)`, then clear the contents of all those cells, then the pivot table *does* group by date ok. i.e., `""` is *not* being treated the same as an empty cell.

Answer (score 2):

i usually use `0` (number, i.e.: `0.1.1900` date) instead of `""` (empty string) and this number format: `[=0]"";d.m.yyyy`

- since you use `,` as a list separator, the number format will probably look like '[=0]"",m/d/yyyy' for you, but i don't know for sure
- in the pivot table, you will find these "blank" values under the year 1900 - i've never had to use actual dates from 1900, so there was no confusion

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a solution for this, please check out my solution at the following post and see if it works for you. 
[Excel Pivot Table recognizing blank cells ("") in column as text not numbers](https://superuser.com/questions/1455936/excel-pivot-table-recognizing-blank-cells-in-column-as-text-not-numbers/1460339#1460339)